# Problem calling FB.ui purchaseItem in mobile chrome

Tags: jquery, facebook-graph-api, facebook-sdk-4.0

When I call FB.ui with the method: pay, action: purchaseItem from my desktop browser it works fine. When I call from a mobile chrome device (iphone6/7/8), its being redirected to a "Page not found" link. What could possibly be wrong?

> Facebook User_id: 2327862263939073
>
> Teste Link: https://www.bolaoapp.com.br/index_test3.html

Steps:

1. Access the link
2. Change chrome device view to IPHONE6/7/8, in developer tools
3. Connect a facebook account
4. Click "pagar" button

```
FB.ui(
    {
        method: "pay",
        action: "purchaseitem",
        product: 'https://www.bolaoapp.com.br/scripts/request_fbpay_moeda-1.10.html',
        quantity: 20,
        pricepoint_id: "teste_pricepoint_id"
    },
    response => (console.log(response))
);
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/payments/reference/paydialog says, _“Only Canvas apps on Facebook.com can open the this dialog.”_ - but the [canvas platform](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/games/gamesonfacebook) is only available on desktops/laptops to begin with, not on mobile. It goes on to say, _“On mobile, this dialog only supports display modetouch.”_ - but I am not sure if that actually makes sense, considering the aforementioned restriction.

Comment: Thanks for the attention. I found a post that talk about a `display:touch | page | popup` parameter for the FB.ui call. I didn't find any doc reference to it. One strange thing is that if you: 1) click the pay button in chrome desktop view mode; 2) after the pay dialog opens, close it, change to mobile view; 3) if you click the pay button again, without refreshing the browser, the payment dialog will open fine. If you refresh the browser before clicking the pay button, it fails.

Comment: Please someone help!